How to assess a tolerance interval study when data needs to be transformed using Johnson transformation
I'm doing a variable data analysis in which I need to perform a tolerance interval assessment to make sure that my population is meeting the Lower specification limit (LSL) of 6 lbf. To be able to perform a tolerance interval analysis I need to demonstrate that the population is following a normal distribution. Given that my data analysis revealed a p-value of less than 0.05, indicating that the data does not follow a normal distribution, I performed a distribution identification analysis and determined that the Johnson transformation was the only suitable fit. However, when calculating the tolerance interval, the result came out as -2.597. How can I assess whether my analysis has been successfully completed and whether the results are valid despite this outcome? AS a reminder, the outcome is a Lower Tolerance interval (LTL) = -2.597 and my Lower spec limit (LSL)= 6 does this mean my study fail to meet the specification? I have read that I need to transform the specification of 6 lbf using Johnson transformation but I'm not sure how.
Thank you

Welcome to CV, Ivan.  We need you to provide more context about this: what analysis are you doing, how do you obtain a p-value, for what hypothesis, how does that tell you anything about normality, what are you trying to use a transformation for, what do you mean by "LSL" and "LTL", what kind of data do you have, and what do you mean by "did not pass"? I feel I can make educated guesses about much of this but they will truly be guesses and I imagine others might guess differently, which can lead all of us astray.

I have added more details. Please let me know if my question makes sense now. Thanks

@whuber, I do vote (fwiw) to reopen the question. The OP added details which now make it clear, w/o much needed guesswork. The question addresses an important topic, namely the use of data transformation to make non-normal data look normal. This is (unfortunately) a common practice in industry (SPC practioners), and the question touches on a key issue: how does one interpret the results obtained on transformed data?
